# I am using socket.io-client and angular2. When I listen to socket's response from server side, the response is accumulating on succeeding request

Tags: angular

[image: img1]

whenever I send a request via emit to the socket and receive a server response.. the
response from server keeps accumulating on succeeding request. I am new to angular2 and new to use socket-io.client.

if I tried socket-io-client on normal HTML and run it on nodejs, it is fine. I am receiving the one-time response. Only on Angular2 that it accumulates. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: please share your code so we can help

Comment: here is the sample code from my component. 

 this.supervisorService.getTeams(this.selectedteam)
                .subscribe((data)=>{                  

                    this.teams =  data;                   

})

Comment: This will be the method on my service. 

 getTeams(id) {        
        let observable = new Observable(observer=>{

        var Object = {            
            campaign_id:id
        };     

        this.socket.emit('my_request_name', Object);

          this.socket.on('my_request_response', function(data){            
                observer.next(data);              
           });

       });
        return observable;     
    }

Comment: will you help me identify why is it happening so I will never do the same mistake again? thank you.